# Cookies are removed on page refresh (AngularJS)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, openid-connect, identityserver3

I am working in Application and in that Application we are using SSO (Single Sign On) and Application stores cookies for Identity Server and that cookies are responsible to various task like "Token Auto refresh", "logout from Application" etc.

But the Problem is that when I do refresh the Page it removes cookies from application. so SSO functionality stops working.

Below are the images of it. first image with stored cookies and another is with after refresh page.

[image: Image with stored cookies]

[image: Image with cookies removed]

How can we persist cookies on page refresh?

I am using AngularJS.

any help would be appreciated

Comment: It's difficult to see since the screenshots are limited, but I'm pretty sure you have session cookies there.  They will be discarded upon a refresh.  If you want a cookie to persist longer it must have a (future) expiration date set.

Comment: Yes. but that cookies are not stored by Code and that are maintain by Identity Server so its hard to set expiration date for it. if you have any solution then please provide it..

Comment: talk to your identity server. you shouldn't be the only ones who have these problem, maybe there is a documentation on how to work with that?